# Xamarin.Forms Listview's ItemDisappearing event is not triggered when the item is removed from the list

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am new with Xamarin.Forms, I have a listview with an item source.

The `ItemSource` of the ListView is an `ObserverableCollection`
Unfortuntaley, when I remove an item from the `ItemSource`, the `ItemDisapperaing` event is not trigged. Yes, the list item is removed from the UI in the Android device.

However I implemented the `ItemAppearing` and that works fine! It triggered.

Adding item working scenario:

1. The `ShopCart.Instance.AddItem(randomItem)` called.
2. `ShopItemListView.ItemsSource` is refreshed with the newly added item.
3. `TotalAmount`'s Text is updated with the right amount.
   **So the ShopItem_NewItemAdded function is called!**

Clearing items from Shopcart scenario (not working)

1. `ShopCart.Instance.Clear()` called.
2. `ShopItemListView.ItemShource` will be empty! The items not on the UI!
3. But the `TotalAmount`'s text does not changed to 0.0! It still has the previous value.

It seems on the UI element the TotalAmount is not refreshed! In Debug I see after the Clear the `ShopItemListView.ItemsSource` list is empty.

So the `ShopItem_ItemRemoved` function is not called!

Here the Xaml.cs

```
public ShopView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new ShopViewModel();

        ShopItemListView.ItemsSource = Shop.Instance.ShopItems;
        // This is triggered, it works
        ShopItemListView.ItemAppearing += ShopItem_NewItemAdded;
        // This event is not triggered, it does not work
        ShopItemListView.ItemDisappearing += ShopItem_ItemRemoved;
    }

    // This event is not triggered, it does not work
    private void ShopItem_ItemRemoved(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
       // If I put a breakpoint here the debugger never comes into this method
        TotalAmount.Text = Shop.Instance.ShopItems.Sum(si => si.Price).ToString();
        if (Shop.Instance.ShopItems.Count == 0) {
            ShopInformation.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }

     // This is triggered, it works.
    private void ShopItem_NewItemAdded(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
    {
        TotalAmount.Text = Shop.Instance.ShopItems.Sum(si => si.Price).ToString();
        ShopInformation.IsVisible = true;
    }
```

Here is the shopcart singleton instance

```
public sealed class ShopCart : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static readonly ShopCart _instance = new ShopCart();

        private ShopCart()
        {
            ShopItems = new ObservableCollection<ShopCartItem>();
        }

        public static ShopCart Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ShopCartItem> ShopItems { get; set; }

        public void AddItem(ShopCartItem ShopCartItem)
        {
            ShopItems.Add(ShopCartItem);
            OnPropertyChanged("ShopItems");
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            ShopItems.Clear();
            OnPropertyChanged("ShopItems");
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

The ShopCart implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. But it seems the UI element is not notified.

How can I refresh the `TotalAmount` Label on the UI after I removed every shop items from the shop cart?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are interchanging names? `Shop.Instance.ShopItems` and `ShopCart.Instance.ShopItems`

Comment: Also, is there a reason this is all done `static`ly? It seems like a shopping cart is something you would have multiple instances of.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mistake the usage of the [ItemDisappearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemDisappearing?view=xamarin-forms). This method is for virtualization usage only. It is not guaranteed to fire for all visible items when the List is removed from the screen.

It means if you have a list of 100 items, but you can only see 10 at a time because of the size of the cells once you scroll down and a new cell comes into view, and the top cell scrolls off the screen the ItemDisappearing event will fire.

If you just want to show the listView's ItemsSource(in your case `ShopItems`'s Count) count on the screen. You can use Binding and Converter:

**Create a converter firstly:**

```
public class ArrayToCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ObservableCollection<ShopCartItem> collection = value as ObservableCollection<ShopCartItem>;

        return "There are" + collection.Count + "items";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Then use it like:**

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ArrayToCountConverter x:Key="ArrayToCountConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Label Text="{Binding ShopItems, Converter={StaticResource ArrayToCountConverter}}"/>
```

**Also you need to set the `BindingContext`:**

```
public ShopCart shopCart = ShopCart.Instance;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.BindingContext = shopCart;

    MyListView.ItemsSource = shopCart.ShopItems;
}
```

In this way when you add or clear the `ShopItems` in the ViewModel, the label will show the count.